# Как добавить зависимость Mockito для Gradle (Kotlin)?

Tags: kotlin, юнит-тесты, gradle, mockito

Добавила в зависимости:

```
dependencies {
testImplementation(kotlin("test"))

testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '2.27.0'
}
```

Результат:

```
build.gradle.kts:17:22: Expecting an element
```

При добавлении:

```
dependencies {
testImplementation(kotlin("test"))

testImplementation (kotlin("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.+"))
}
```

Результат:

```
untitled11:test: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-org.mockito:mockito-core.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-org.mockito/mockito-core/kotlin-org.mockito-mockito-core.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
    project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Что делать и как использовать Mockito в Kotlin-проекте? (Версия, если что - kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21")

Comment: Попробуйте так `testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.12.4")`, а не так `testImplementation(kotlin("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.+"))`

Comment: Список всех версий и как их подключать в Gradle можно посмотреть здесь: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно объявили зависимость, попробуйте так:

```kotlin
testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.12.4")
```

Функцию `kotlin()` здесь не нужно использовать. Кроме этого, лучше задавать конкретную версию, без плюсиков. Иначе ваша сборка может в любой момент поломаться при выходе новой версии библиотеки.

На сайте https://mvnrepository.com вы всегда можете проверить, как правильно указывать зависимость: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.12.4

Comment: Спасибо, все верно, извиняюсь, а дальше в классах писать import org.mockito...? Ещё раз извиняюсь за очень глупые вопросы, я только начинаю работать с Котлин, а в курсе, который я смотрю, используется то, что у меня не работает, как, например, здесь (почему и был задан вопрос)

Comment: [На сайте проекта Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) есть базовый пример, там делают импорт так: `import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;`